# How to perform scale to fit / fill?

Tags: blitline

I want to scale an image to fit or fill certain width while keeping the aspect ratio.

For example, when the server receives 1200x800 image without knowing the image size and I want to scale it down to 300x200 by specifying only width=300.

Note that I would specify either width or height, not both.
Also, I wouldn't want to scale up to make it bigger size, if the original image is small.

Comment: I will try this at home, but I was responded that `resize_to_fit` can be called with only one param, width or height. So the doc may be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resize_to_fit` does what I want.

Even though, [doc](http://docs.blitline.com/articles/function_list.html#resize_to_fit) says both `width` and `height` are required, you can actually perform `scale_to_fit` effect by providing either only `width` or only `height` to `resize_to_fit` function.